# ASP.NET chat app data storing

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, chat

I'm trying to create a web api for a chat app using ASP .NET and I'm stuck at the way I should store all the messages sent.

In this tutorial https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-aspnet/ author stores all messages in one DB. They find all messages related to one dialog with this line:

```
conversations = db.Conversations.Where(c => (c.receiver_id == currentUser.id 
                                  && c.sender_id == contact) || 
                                  (c.receiver_id == contact 
                                  && c.sender_id == currentUser.id))
    .OrderBy(c => c.created_at).ToList();
```

And I find this method way too slow. I made some calculations and found that if you have 100 active users sending about 30 messages each, there will be a million messages in a year. Cycling through a million lines every time will make the app work slow as molasses.

Still I find it convenient for me to use Entity Framework to work with DB.

So what is the right way to store such an arrays of data like messages? Should it be a separate DB for each conversation? If yes, is there any way to create them automatically with Entity Framework? Or maybe there might be any better solution?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I would like to create an ASP .NET core app if it makes any difference

Comment: I would say that if you are dealing with large amounts of data and are concerned about performance, do not use an ORM. I'd explore other possibilities, SQL is not the only fruit.

Comment: @SteveJ Could you please tell me some more information about it? Any examples or tutorials?

Comment: How are you hosting the app? If it's on a platform such as AWS there are many options for scalable persistance...

Comment: With proper indexing and data normalisation, million records in SQL Server (I presume this is SQL Server) is not a problem. I have a table with over a million records and just now got a handful of records returned to me in milliseconds. Also you can archive the old conversations - say anything older than 3 months is moved to "Archive" table so it is not actively queried. There are so many things you can do to fix performance here, it is very hard to start explaining

Comment: @SteveJ I use azure to store it

Comment: Also, premature optimisation is a root of all evil. Make sure you have that problem first, then go ahead of solving it.

Comment: @trailmax Yeah, I've been thinking about archiving old data, but was not sure it's a proper way to go

Comment: Even millions of messages is not a problem, the whole idea is the operations you do. Which means what is ur algorithm for storing and reading. For reading for example you can use virualization or as fb does each time you scroll up u retrieve set of mesaages. But The tools you are using is fine

Comment: Agree with @trailmax. I just don't really like ORMs because you have no control over the SQL generated and whether it uses indexes you've set up, etc.

Comment: @SteveJ You can use hand-crafted SQL where you need it in EF.

Comment: I also agree with the 'premature optimization' statement to an extent, but I think it refers to micro-optimizations in routines. If you are expecting something to scale, you need to at least think about the big picture architecture early on otherwise you'll end up having to re-write large swathes of code or change architecture completely.

Comment: There's some interesting things here: http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 1):

A million records is peanuts. Why do you think this would be too slow? As trailmax said: it should be trivial for a relational database to get the required records, given that your indices and keys are up to snuff.

**Disregard the following. I wasn't thinking properly**
What you should also consider if you really want to be the one responsible for storing conversations between people server-side.

Comment: Do you know any better way to store them? Like 3rd party service? Share it if you think it's better to use, I'll check it out

Comment: With stuff like GDPR and related privacy rulings, you have an incentive to save as little as possible in the way of privacy-related stuff on your own servers. However, I was clearly having a brainfart, since it's quite hard for an ASP.NET kind of application not to get its data from a centralized place.